# SSL certificate for communication between load balancer and servers necessary?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I am using the Google Cloud Platform to implement a REST API which is accessible through HTTPS only using a load balancer.

My setup looks like this:

**VM instances:**

- 2 instances which run the same node.js server. One outputs "server1" the other outputs "server2".

**Instance groups:**

- One instance group which contains both VMs.

**Back-end services:**

- One back-end service which uses the instance groups and a simple health check.

**Load balancing:**

- One load balancer.
- Frontend: HTTPS PUBLIC_IP:443 my-ssl-certificate
- Backend: My back-end service
- Host and path rules: All unmatched (default)    => My back-end service (default)

I now configured my domain's (api.domain.com) DNS with an A-Record for PUBLIC_IP. https://api.domain.com's output successfully switches between "server1" and "server2". The load balancer and the HTTPS-certificate my-ssl-certificate is working great! my-ssl-certificate is a Let's Encrypt SSL-certificate for my domain api.domain.com.

**Question**: Do I need 2 other certificates for my 2 VM instances, when they communicate with the load balancer? Or is this communication internally and doesn't require further SSL-certificates? If I need those certificates, how do I set them up with IPs?
Because accessing my 2 VM instances IPs via https://VM1_PUBLIC_IP results in a chrome warning, that the certificate is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using load-balancer with SSL certificates, then there was no need  of public facing VM's, you should kept it private subnets and communication should happen over private ip's between LB and VM.

Comment: So the IPs of the 2 VMs shouldnt be public accessible?

Comment: Yes, any reason you want it pubically accessible?

Comment: No reason. I just can't get it to work without allowing https access, when starting the 2 VMs. My load balancer returns a 502 error. How to fix that?

Comment: I just had to leave my external IP enabled and adjust my firewall rules, so only the load balancer and the health check can access the VMs via the public IPs.